# How embedding layer works when the length of inputs are not fixed for each batch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding

I'm reading the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition". In chapter 16 the author explains Sentiment Analysis using imdb reviews.
When I was debugging snippets codes I found that the input length of vectors varies between each batch. Here you can all the code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

datasets, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

def preprocess(X, y):
    text = tf.strings.lower(X)
    text = tf.strings.substr(text, 0, 300)
    text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, "<br\\s*/?>", " ")
    text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, "[^a-z0-9']", " ")
    text = tf.strings.split(text)
    return text.to_tensor(default_value="<pad>"), y

vocabulary = Counter()
for X_batch, y_batch in train_set.batch(10).map(preprocess):
    for review in X_batch:
        vocabulary.update(review.numpy())

vocab_size = 10000
vocabulary = [word for word, freq in vocabulary.most_common(vocab_size)]

lookup_init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(vocabulary, np.array(range(len(vocabulary))))

num_oov_buckets = 1000
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(lookup_init, num_oov_buckets=num_oov_buckets)

def encode_words(X, y):
    return table.lookup(X), y

train_set = datasets["train"]
train_set = train_set.batch(32).map(preprocess)
train_set = train_set.map(encode_words).prefetch(1)

test_set = datasets["test"]
test_set = test_set.batch(32).map(preprocess)
test_set = test_set.map(encode_words).prefetch(1)

additional_train_set = test_set.take(468)
test_set = test_set.skip(468)

train_set = train_set.concatenate(additional_train_set).prefetch(1)

embed_size = 128
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size + num_oov_buckets, embed_size, mask_zero=True,
                           input_shape=[None]),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
hist = model.fit(train_set, epochs=2, validation_data=test_set)

model.evaluate(train_set)
```

this runs OK!

And you can see below X shapes:

```
next = iter.next()
print("X shape =", next[0].shape, "y shape =", next[1].shape)

next = iter.next()
print("X shape =", next[0].shape, "y shape =", next[1].shape)

next = iter.next()
print("X shape =", next[0].shape, "y shape =", next[1].shape)
```

Output

```
X shape = (32, 62) y shape = (32,)
X shape = (32, 60) y shape = (32,)
X shape = (32, 64) y shape = (32,)
```

So... how the embedding layer work since inputs doesn't have a fix length for all batches?

Comment: It works because you are using the input shape None, which allows you to have various input lengths

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes, I know but i meant how it works conceptualy.

Comment: Explain your question.. what exactly do you want to know ?